# Proof that there is no Banach-Tarski paradox in $\Bbb R^2$ using finitely additive invariant set functions?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, paradoxes

I am wondering if anyone is familiar with the above topic? I have found a proof that it is possible to define a finitely additive invariant set function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ on the circle in Lax's book "Functional Analysis". He follows the proof up by saying that this proves that there is no banach-tarski paradox in the plane but I don't see why. Is it obvious? If it isn't can anyone tell me where I can find a proof of this using the existence of such functions? Cheers

Comment: By saying the funcion is "in $\mathbb{R}^2$ does that mean it is defined as a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself? If so what does the other phrase "on the circle" mean? On the unit circle? In short what is the domain and range of the function in Lax's book which he shows exist? It's not clear from your phrasing. And I don't have Lax's book.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What Lax shows is that there is a finitely additive, rotationally invariant set function $m \colon P(S^1) \to [0,1]$ on the circle such that $m(S^1) = 1$:

> **Theorem 4.** *One can define a nonnegative finitely additive set function $m(P)$, for all subsets $P$ of the circle, that is invariant under rotation.*

This implies in particular that it is impossible to decompose $S^1$ paradoxically into a disjoint union of finitely many pieces $A_1,\dots,A_n$ in such a way that $S^1$ can be written as disjoint union of rotated versions of $A_1,\dots,A_k$ as well as $A_{k+1},\dots,A_n$, i.e.,
$r_1 A_1 \cup \cdots \cup r_k A_k = S^1$ and $r_{k+1} A_{k+1} \cup \cdots \cup r_{n} A_{k+1} = S^1$ where $r_1,\dots,r_n$ are some rotations.

Indeed, we would have
$$
1 = m(S^1) = m(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) = m(A_1) + \dots +m(A_n)
$$
as well as
$$
\begin{align*}
1 & = m(S^1) = m(r_1 A_1 \cup \dots \cup r_k A_k) = m(A_1) + \dots + m(A_k) \cr
1 & = m(S^1) = m(r_{k+1} A_{k+1} \cup \dots \cup r_{n}A_n) = m(A_{k+1}) + \dots + m(A_{n})
\end{align*}
$$
by finite additivity and invariance of $m$ under rotations. In particular,
$$1 = m(A_1) + \dots +m(A_n) = [m(A_1) + \dots + m(A_k)] + [m(A_{k+1}) + \dots + m(A_{n})] = 2$$
which is absurd.

If you want to show that there is no Banach-Tarski paradox in the plane, you would need a finitely additive set-function $P(\mathbb{R}^2) \to [0,1]$ invariant under isometries and argue as above. Banach showed that such a set function *does* exist (and the proof is slightly harder because the group of affine isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not commutative; the key-word here is [amenability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group)). Lax does not establish that fact, but neither does he claim to disprove Banach-Tarski in the *plane*, he only talks about the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and mentions that Hausdorff disproved the existence of a finitely additive rotationally invariant set function on the $2$-sphere:

> NOTE. Rotations of the circle commute with each other, and so the operators $\mathbf{A}_\rho$ commute; this was needed in invoking theorem 7 of chapter 3. Rotations of the three-dimensional sphere do *not* commute, and neither do the corresponding operators $\mathbf{A}_\rho$. Therefore the above proof cannot be used to extended theorem 4 to three dimensions. In fact Hausdorff has shown that the three-dimensional analogue of theorem 4 is *false*; there is *no* rotational invariant, finitely additive set function on the $2$-sphere. The proof is based on a finite decomposition of the $2$-sphere, sometimes called the Banach-Tarski paradox.

Note that there is a bit of confusion about the dimensions: Lax talks about the unit sphere in the three-dimensional space and calls that thing both the three-dimensional sphere and the $2$-sphere.

All this and much more is very readably explained in Stan Wagon's book [The Banach-Tarski Paradox](http://www.cambridge.org/9780521457040).