# Version of the Banach-Tarski Paradox for Tori

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

Are there versions of the Banach-Tarski paradox for topological spaces of genus greater than one?

If so, how many pieces are required to turn a torus into two tori of equal size?

Is there a general formula for the minimum number of pieces for doubling an object of a given genus?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem with torus is that the only isometries of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that preserve it are rotations along fixed line, i.e. $S^1$. Right? And $S^1$ (as a group) cannot be paradoxically decomposed similarly to $\mathbb{F}_2$ (being a subgroup of rotations of 2-dimensional ball/sphere). Therefore the original proof doesn't work for torus. And my intuition tells me that torus is not paradoxical.

Comment: @freakish I thought $S^1$ could be paradoxically decomposed with infinitely many pieces, whether that means a torus requires infinitely many pieces or not I don't know.

Comment: $S^1$ cannot be paradoxically decomposed into finitely many pieces as [you can see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380184/proof-that-there-is-no-banach-tarski-paradox-in-bbb-r2-using-finitely-additi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). I'm not sure about infinity though. But that would not be a classical definition of paradoxical set.

Comment: Is the Banach-Tarski paradox even topologically invariant?? For example, can a cube be paradoxically decomposed into five pieces, or any other object topologically equivalent to a sphere?

Comment: @freakish "S1 is countably SO2-paradoxical" - a Google search of this statement will give you lots of references.

Comment: the concept of paradoxical set is not a topological concept but rather $G$-topological, i.e. you need a group acting on the set. In the standard case: all isometries preserving the subset. From that point of view it is easy to construct a homeomorphic but not paradoxical set: bend the sphere so much that it is not invariant under any non-trivial isometry.

Comment: the cube has finite group of isometries and I think it is not paradoxical but as with my other statements: I can't prove that. :(

Comment: @freakish Wikipedia states that Tarski's circle-squaring problem is the challenge, posed by Alfred Tarski in 1925, to take a disc in the plane, cut it into finitely many pieces, and reassemble the pieces so as to get a square of equal area. This was proven to be possible by Miklós Laczkovich in 1990; the decomposition makes heavy use of the axiom of choice and is therefore non-constructive. Laczkovich estimated the number of pieces in his decomposition at roughly 10^50. More recently, in 2017, Andrew Marks and Spencer Unger gave a completely constructive solution using Borel pieces.

Comment: @freakish if the square can be decomposed into a circle, then maybe a cube can be decomposed into a sphere. Further half a torus might be able to be decomposed into a sphere. Then one could at least provide a possible paradoxical decomposition by applying the standard Banach-Tarski paradox, even if it didn't provide the minimum number of pieces.

Comment: hmm, that's very interesting. Perhaps my intuition was wrong all the time. I'd love to dive deeper into the topic. Lack of time though...